py2app application is not working on other Macs, why?
I have created an application using py2app and it's working perfectly on my Mac.
Now, I have to send it to some friends. When they download it, either from Wetransfer or Google Drive or whatever, it doesn't work.
It says The app is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.
As a double-check, I also downloaded it and on my Mac, it says the same thing.
The same app opened from the dist folder of the Python project and from the downloaded folder is working only in the first case.
What is the problem?
I see there are other questions on the same topic, but there is no solution, or it's not working in my case, or they are too old.

How are you creating the file to send to your friends? It's likely that you're creating the file to upload/download incorrectly, which is causing the problem.

I tried with simple compress from right-click and also this commandzip -yr $NAME.app.zip $NAME.app from a guide online

If I uncompress the zip, the app works perfectly, so the problem is the transfer somehow.

That error message generally indicates a problem with code signing (e.g. the actual binary not matching the signature, or something like that). macOS quarantines downloaded files, and does more stringent checking on them, which is presumably why it's only happening when the program is downloaded. So you need to diagnose & correct how the code is signed.

Any suggestions on how to do that? It’s the first time I hear it :)

It's likely related to the quarantine flag being set on the app - general suggestion is to remove it, as long as you're confident that it's ok to run is to do xattr -rc $NAME.app, and it should run. because this is a py2app executable; it's definitely not codesigned in any way

Thanks @AnyaShenanigans this command solved the problem. If you answer the question I close it and upvote the answer

I’m voting to close this question because it's already answered on the askdifferent site at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372084/macos-catalina-app-is-damaged-and-cant-be-opened-you-should-move-it-to-the-t
